# Want to read a keyevent down and print the key evertime a key is pressed when the browser window is active?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write simple JavaScript function that will display the name of everykey that I press whenever I press the key. I am going to try and create a game like the old centipede game but I need to be able to scan for keys every time a key goes down.

**Question: How do I need to change this code to make it scan and write out the name of the key on a key down event request?**

HTML code:

```
<body onload="docReady()" onkeydown="checkForNewKey()" onkeyup="" bgcolor='black'>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="450" height="600" style="border:1px solid #00FFFF;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

code:

```
function checkForNewKey(){
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");  <-- Exactly why does this need to be here and what does it do?

    ctx.font="30px Arial";
    var temp = evt.keyCode;
     ctx.fillText(temp,20,50);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use keypress event. Not sure what your end goal is for writing to canvas, but check this out for more info:
http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html

For the letter writing, this works:

**JSFiddle**   http://jsfiddle.net/kS7S3/

```
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
   var evt = evt || window.event;
   var charCode = typeof evt.which == "number" ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
   console.log(charCode, String.fromCharCode(charCode));

   var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   var ctx=c.getContext("2d");  
   ctx.font="30px Arial";
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,100,100);
   ctx.fillText(String.fromCharCode(charCode),20,50);

   return true; // proceed as usual
};
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="width:100px;;height:100px;background-color:red;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Well, I want to see about making a centipede game all with java script. I thought that writing to a canvas would keep it all in the same object. What are the better options?